# Python username validation in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

I have got a csv file with userdata for an assignment for school.

My problem is that the username I entered and stored in the file isn't getting **validated** to the one I enter when I read the data and enter it to login

```
def Load(): #Loads data from the csv that can be stored in variables
  global userdata
  global user
  userdata = []
  f = open('userdata.csv','r')
  data = csv.reader(f)
  user = []
  for row in data:
      for field in row:
          user.append(field)
      userdata.append(user)
  f.close()
```

Load function that opens the file and reads the data

```
def Login(): #Login function
  Load()
  print('Please now login to your account')

  x = False
  while not x:
      usernameLog = input('Please enter your username: ')

      j = len(userdata)
      for i in range(0,j):
          if usernameLog == userdata[i][0]: #Compares username to one in the csv file
            print('Username accepted')
```

Login function which fails to validate the username I entered vs the one stored in the program

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the csv too

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def Load(): #Loads data from the csv that can be stored in variables

    userdata = []
    f = open('file.csv','r')
    data = csv.reader(f)
    users = []
    print(data)
    for row in data:
        for field in row:
            users.append(field)
    f.close()
    return users

def Login(): #Login function
    userdata = Load()
    print('Please now login to your account')
    x = False
    while x == False:
        usernameLog = input('Please enter your username: ')
        for i in range(len(userdata)):
            if usernameLog == userdata [i]: #Compares username to one in the csv file
                print('Username accepted')
                x = True
Login()
```

Comment: That is imported at the top of the program